# Parsing CSV and storing values into variables

Tags: bash

bash newbie here.  I am trying to figure out how to read the email parts of a CSV files so that I can use it to email them the other items of the CSV.  For instance (see sample CSV below), I will need to send email1@domain.com his order of fries,and burger.

```
Email,orders,Status
email1@domain.com,fries,fulfilled
email1@domain.com,burger,fulfilled
email1@domain.com,soda,Not fulfilled
email2@domain.com,soda,fulfilled
email2@domain.com,burger,Not fulfilled
email2@domain.com,fries,fulfilled
email3@domain.com,soda,fulfilled
email3@domain.com,burger,fulfilled
email4@domain.com,fries,Not fulfilled
email5@domain.com,soda,Not fulfilled
email5@domain.com,fries,fulfilled
email5@domain.com,burger,fulfilled
```

I am a bit of a loss on to where to actually begin. I have this:

```
cat "result.csv" | while IFS=',' read -r line; do
  email="$(echo "$line" | cut -d ',' -f 1)"
  order="$(echo "$line" | cut -d ',' -f 2)"
done
```

But I could not figure out how to advance 1 line to see if I need to include the order from the next line (if the email address is the same as what the script is currently reading.)  Bash and python solutions are welcome :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is code to accumulate the order over lines.  A more challenging task.  Assuming you're using bash version 4 or higher, this will work.  If you are on version 3 of bash, the final email address will be blank.  I actually am using version 3 of bash (arg- Apple you suck), so I hope I got it right.  I filled in the last line by hand.

```
#!/bin/bash

previous_email=""

full_order=""

IFS=,
(while  read -r current_email order status; do
        # echo $current_email $order $status
        if [[ "$current_email" == 'Email' ]] ; then
            previous_email="Email"
        else
            if [[ $current_email != $previous_email  ]] ; then
                # Destination email changed

                if [[ $previous_email == "Email"  ]] ; then
                    # Nothing to print from header line 
                        previous_email=$current_email
                if [[ "$status" == "fulfilled" ]]; then
                                    full_order=$order
                            else
                                    full_order=""
                    fi
                else
                    # Do summary

                    if [[ $full_order == "" ]] ; then
                            printf "$previous_email  - You have no orders\n"
                    else    
                            printf "$previous_email  - Your order is $full_order\n  "
                    fi

                    previous_email=$current_email

                if [[ "$status" == "fulfilled" ]]; then
                                    full_order=$order
                            else
                                    full_order=""
                    fi
                fi  

            else  # continue with same email
            if [[ "$status" == "fulfilled" ]]; then
                        if [[ $full_order == "" ]] ; then
                                full_order=$order
                        else
                                full_order="$full_order, $order"
                        fi
                fi
        fi
fi
done < result.csv

printf "$current_email your order is $full_order\n" )


sh prog.sh
email1@domain.com  - Your order is fries, burger
email2@domain.com  - Your order is soda, fries
email3@domain.com  - Your order is soda, burger
email4@domain.com  - You have no orders
email5@domain.com  your order is fries, burger
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `read` command would split the line, if you provided enough names to be assigned to.

```
while IFS=, read -r email order status; do
  if [ "$status" != fulfilled ]; then
    echo "$email ordered $order, but still awaiting delivery"
  else
    echo "$email received their $order"
  fi
done < result.csv
```

In general, `bash` can only handle simple CSV files like this, where there are no quoted commas. It is recommended to use a language with a proper CSV parsing library instead of `bash`.

Comment: Thanks chepner but I will need to consolidate my output i.e. _email1@domain.com  - Your order is fries, burger_
 
@Leonard 's answer below is more appropriate for my use case:-).

and you are correct, I will need to use a language with proper CSV parsing...  I am looking at python if I have the time to re-learn it.